# Admin Force CheckIn Documents and Consequences

Tags: check-in

I'm using PowerShell to loop through all documents in document libraries in a site collection that are Checked-Out to force CheckIn on them.

What I'm wondering is:

What happens if the checked-out document has a local "offline" copy at the end user client computer? Will the new [Checked-In] server version and the local "offline" version [at the end user client computer] still be intact?

Thanks in advance!